# After converting image to binary cannot display it in notebook with matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, matplotlib, imshow

I am trying to display the image After coverting the image to binary in python notebook:

```
resized_img = cv2.cvtColor(char_mask, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
resized_img = cv2.threshold(resized_img, 100, 200, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
#cv2.imwrite('licence_plate_mask3.png', char_mask)
plt.imshow(resized_img)

plt.show()
```

I cannot show image. I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-0a3eb57cc497> in <module>()
      8 resized_img = cv2.threshold(resized_img, 100, 200, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
      9 #cv2.imwrite('licence_plate_mask3.png', char_mask)
---> 10 plt.imshow(resized_img)
     11 
     12 plt.show()

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in imshow(X, cmap, norm, aspect, interpolation, alpha, vmin, vmax, origin, extent, shape, filternorm, filterrad, imlim, resample, url, hold, data, **kwargs)
   3155                         filternorm=filternorm, filterrad=filterrad,
   3156                         imlim=imlim, resample=resample, url=url, data=data,
-> 3157                         **kwargs)
   3158     finally:
   3159         ax._hold = washold

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in inner(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1895                     warnings.warn(msg % (label_namer, func.__name__),
   1896                                   RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
-> 1897             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1898         pre_doc = inner.__doc__
   1899         if pre_doc is None:

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in imshow(self, X, cmap, norm, aspect, interpolation, alpha, vmin, vmax, origin, extent, shape, filternorm, filterrad, imlim, resample, url, **kwargs)
   5122                               resample=resample, **kwargs)
   5123 
-> 5124         im.set_data(X)
   5125         im.set_alpha(alpha)
   5126         if im.get_clip_path() is None:

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py in set_data(self, A)
    590             self._A = pil_to_array(A)
    591         else:
--> 592             self._A = cbook.safe_masked_invalid(A, copy=True)
    593 
    594         if (self._A.dtype != np.uint8 and

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook.py in safe_masked_invalid(x, copy)
   1504 
   1505 def safe_masked_invalid(x, copy=False):
-> 1506     x = np.array(x, subok=True, copy=copy)
   1507     if not x.dtype.isnative:
   1508         # Note that the argument to `byteswap` is 'inplace',

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Before using threshold I can see the image inside the notebook without problem. Any way to resolve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error lies in line `resized_img = cv2.threshold(resized_img, 100, 200, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)`.

`cv2.threshold()` returns two values. The first is the threshold value (float) and the second is the image.

So all the while you have been trying to plot a `float` value, hence the *Value error*.

Rewrite the line to the following:

```
ret, resized_img = cv2.threshold(resized_img, 100, 200, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

You can have a look [at the documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html) as well.